# Zend framework: about bootstrape and application class

Tags: php, zend-framework

what's the diff:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(...);
$application->bootstrap()->run();

$application = new Zend_Application(...);
$application->run();
```

why we need call ->bootstrape then call ->run? why not just call application->run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the Zend Sources class:Zend_Application,  file:application.php

```
public function bootstrap($resource = null)
{
    $this->getBootstrap()->bootstrap($resource);
    return $this;
}

public function run()
{
    $this->getBootstrap()->run();
}
```

The first sample

```
$application = new Zend_Application(...);
$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

calls Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap::bootstrap method which ends up loading all the resources.
Then it calls `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap::run()` which actually dispatches the request.

The second sample

```
$application = new Zend_Application(...);
$application->run();
```

according to the code above is skipping the first step, so it will try to run (dispatch the request) without actually loading the resources.
 This is how Zend [describes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html) bootstrapping and resources.